# Use jQuery selectors on HTML that is stored in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array with some HTML in it, so something like:

```
var array=[
           "<div anAttribute=19 class='foo'>This is the content of the foo div.</div>", 
           "<div anAttribute=14 class='bar'>This is the content of the bar div.</div>"
          ];
```

I want to get the value of anAttribute for both of them.

```
array[0].$('.foo').attr("anAttribute");
```

Would return 19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
$(array[0]).attr("anAttribute");
$(array[1]).attr("anAttribute");
```

I am assuming `anAttribute` is a valid html attribute, if not prefix it with `data-*`.

Comment: You can make up custom attributes like that in HTML5. Thank you for your answer, I'll accept it ASAP!

Comment: @ebol4 yes custom attributes must be prefixed with data-* in HTML 5

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the attributes in an array:

```
var attributes = $(array.join('')).map(function(){
  return $(this).attr('anAtribute');
}).get();
```

Then you can access them like:

```
attributes[0] //= 19
attributes[1] //= 14
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to wrap the string in the jquery closure:

```
jQuery(array[0]).attr('anAttribute');
```

will return 19